# What happens if someone does something illegal on a server you host at home?

Tags: internet

Let's say you start up a Gmail-type service and somebody sells drugs with it/distributes child pornography, would SWAT raid my house if bad people used my website?

I'm interested in an answer under the jurisdiction of the USA.

Comment: I'm just curious, is your ISP cool with you running a public email server out of your home?

Comment: You will likely find [this info from NIST](http://www.nist.gov/itl/upload/StopBadware_Web-Hosting-Provider-Liability-for-Malicious-Content.pdf) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If the police (including federal law enforcement agencies) could show probable cause that evidence of a crime could be found on the servers in your house, they could get a judge to issue a search warrant.  Presumably, emails relating to the illegal activities would be evidence, and would likely be found on your servers.

The warrant would permit them to enter your house and seize the evidence (the server, and perhaps any other evidence they encountered).  If they could convince the judge that someone might try to destroy evidence when they arrived, they could potentially get a [no-knock warrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-knock_warrant).

Whether or not they brought a SWAT team would be at the discretion of the police; it isn't really a question of law.